# accessing $(this) value returns undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jquery-select2

I am trying to access `$(this)` inside the select2 initialization, but it returns `undefined`.

```
$(".tags").each(function() {
    var placeholder = "Select Email";
    if($(this).attr('name') === 'names[]')
        placeholder = "Select Name";
    $(this).select2({
        tags: true,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        language: {
            noResults: function () {
                return 'Type and enter to add new';
            },
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        },
        createTag: function(params) {
            console.log($(this).attr('name')); // returns undefined
            if (params.term.indexOf('@') === -1)
                return null;
            return {
                id: params.term,
                text: params.term
            }
        }
    })
});
```

`select2()` is initialized for each `.tags`. I need to access `$(this)` inside the initialization here.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback This might give you additional info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the `createTag` function does not run under the scope of the element which `select2` was instantiated on.

To fix this you would need to retain a reference to the original element, which can be done by storing it in a variable in the `each()` handler:

```js
$(".tags").each(function() {
  var $tag = $(this);

  // other logic...

  $tag.select2({
    // other logic...
    createTag: function(params) {
      console.log($tag.prop('name'));

      if (params.term.indexOf('@') === -1)
        return null;

      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can hold a reference to `$(this)` before calling `select2()`

```
$(".tags").each(function() {
    var placeholder = "Select Email";
    var $that = $(this);


    if($that.attr('name') === 'names[]')
        placeholder = "Select Name";
    $that.select2({
        tags: true,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        language: {
            noResults: function () {
                return 'Type and enter to add new';
            },
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        },
        createTag: function(params) {
            console.log($that.attr('name'));
            if (params.term.indexOf('@') === -1)
                return null;
            return {
                id: params.term,
                text: params.term
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Hope this helps